# Using vue, determine which radio input is selected by accessing $refs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I populate some radio buttons from an array of options. I would like to determine which radio button was select using $refs, however when I log out the $refs it gives me all of the radio buttons.

Is it possible to just grab the select radio button using $refs? Can you some how combine event.target with the $refs or something? Furthermore how to I access parts of that ref like the class of the element that was selected. I am trying to use just vue to do this but has proven difficult.

thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<li
          class="mc-option"
          v-for="(option, i) in options"
          :key="i">

<input
        ref="mcOption"
        type="radio"
        name="option"
        :id="'option-' + i"
        class=""
        @click="radioSelected($event)">

</li>

methods: {
  radioSelected: function () {
      let mcOption = this.$refs.mcOption
      console.log(mcOption)
    },)
}
```

Comment: You could check if a radio button is checked by checking its `checked` property.

Comment: But you probably want to store the selected option in your `data`.

Comment: Think I am on to something actually. If I use a foreach and and then check if it is checked or not

Comment: Sometimes you just have to write it out on stack and you it starts to come together haha.

Comment: Why don't you use v-model? You get the value of the checked radio easily without hassle

Answer (score 0):

X is your ID:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="x in 5">
        <label :for="`radio${x}`">radio{{x}}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" :id="`radio${x}`" @change="getRef(`radio${x}`)" :ref="`radio${x}`">
    </li>
</ul>

methods: {
getRef (ref) {
  console.log(this.$refs[ref])
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since all the generated options are having the same `ref` ids. You could come over this with the following code.

TEMPLATE

```
<li class="mc-option" v-for="(option, i) in options" :key="i">
            <input :ref="['mcOption',i].join('-')" type="radio" name="option" :id="'option-' + i" class="" @click="radioSelected(i)"> {{i+1}}
</li>
```

JS

```
methods: {
            radioSelected: function (i) {
                let mcOption = this.$refs[['mcOption', i].join('-')]
                console.log(mcOption)
            }
        }
```

Points to note are:

- `:ref`
- a variable ref id by using `['mcOption', i].join('-')`. This actually can be anything you want (but should change for every v-for iteration).

Please let me know if it does NOT work for you.